# encode serialization byte array into std::string

Tags: c++, encoding, stl, hypertable

Is there a standard way to **encode** and **decode** byte arrays into a sequence of characters that can be stored into a `std::string`?

The reason for this question is that HyperTable value type is `std::string`, so whatever custom type you want to store in the table needs to be *serialised* and stored into the string, and then, *deserialized* for reading. (see this thread for details: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/hypertable-user/_igfvLv9IfA)

Comment: `std::string(byteArray, byteArray+size)`? Are the byte arrays interdependent (do they contain data that must be changed when they are deserialised)?

Comment: @Mankarse, the problem with that simple approach is that, according to the documentation detail link i posted on the question, the SELECT will un-escape \n \t and \\ one-byte versions into their two-byte versions. So if my binary data contains one of those bytes by chance they will be unescaped, corrupting the data.  My hope was that this problem was so common that a std function would exist somewhere for this. I've since wrote one and it seems to work but i'm happy to replace it with something standard, i hate reinventing the wheel

Comment: There is no standard way to do this, but if I understand correctly, it could be implemented in less than 10 lines of code.

Comment: did you try to escape your strings before writing them? if you do it yourself the HT process combined with you own decode won't corrupt the data